# Proof of Non-Convexity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-analysis

Am looking for a proof of non-convexity of the quotient of two matrix trace functions as given by $\frac{\operatorname{Tr}X^TAX}{\operatorname{Tr}X^TBX}$, when $TrX^TBX>0$
for two different positive semi-definite matrices , $A$ and $B$ such that $A \neq \alpha B$ for any scalar $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for making the point. I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: In fact not equal up to a constant ($A=\alpha B$ where $\alpha$ is a scalar).

Comment: That's right again, taking the inverse into consideration.

Comment: You also have a definition issue, because it is perfectly possible that for some $X$ your denominator is zero (for example if $B$ is not invertible and $X$ is the projection onto the kernel of $B$).

Comment: Updated and awaiting the proof.

Comment: You still have issues with your definition: if $B$ is not invertible, then the denominator will still be zero for many $X$.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me if you are asking about the convexity of the function, or of the set of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but a specific counterexample demonstrates 'non-convexity':

Choose

$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 10
\end{array} \right),
B = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
10 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right),
X(t) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & t
\end{array} \right).
$$
Some manipulation yields:
$$\phi(t) = \frac{\mathbb{tr}(X^T A X)}{\mathbb{tr}(X^T B X)} = \frac{10 t^2+1}{t^2+10}.$$
The function $\phi$ is not convex (for example, $\phi(5) > \frac{1}{2}(\phi(0)+\phi(10))$.